# Is there a good and secure way to allow non-root user to start a docker image?

Tags: docker

I have a scenario where I want to let non-root users start a docker image and run it. It's a very simple image - we have a stupid proprietary piece of software that insists on blocking a certain port, making concurrent runs of that software impossible. I was thinking to fix that with docker.

Problem is that normal users (it's a part of a compile process) should be able to spin this up. How do I go about that in a sane and secure fashion?

Comment: you can add that user to `docker` group. It should be there after docker installation.

Comment: Docker is designed to be executed by non-privileged users. The only requirement for the regular users to run `docker` is to [belong to the `docker` group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/).

Comment: @Rafal @axiac Being member of group `docker` is `root` equivalent. Users that should not have root privileges must NOT be members of group `docker`. Compare e.g. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9976

Answer (score 4):

If the desired `docker` command is static, create a simple start script, store in in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executeable. Make an entry in `/etc/sudoers` to allow desired users to run this command with sudo without a password.

E.g create file `/usr/local/bin/alpine.docker`:

```
#! /bin/sh
docker run --rm -it alpine sh
```

Make the script secure (non root user should not be able to edit it):

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/alpine.docker
```

Set reasonable permissions and make it executeable:

```
sudo chmod 554 /usr/local/bin/alpine.docker
```

Create an entry in `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`:

```
username  ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/alpine.docker
```

Now the user `username` can run `sudo alpine.docker` without a password.

---

Warning:

Don't add users to group `docker` if they should not have root privileges.

Note:

For this solution, you need to install `sudo`. But the user `username` does not need to be member of group `sudo`.

Note 2:

A similar setup is possible with policykit / `pkexec`. But I am not familar with it.

Comment: This is the preferred solution, but I think it could be made more elegant by creating a new group `stubbornapp`, giving the restricted sudo privileges to the `stubbornapp` group and adding users to the `stubbornapp` group appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876910/348975 solution, but an alternative is to use something like docker machine https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876910/348975 or dind https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ to create a brand new throwaway docker.

Then you set the environment variable export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://${IP_ADDRESS}:2376 and can use **that docker** without root.

This is probably not necessary for OPs case, but where it would come in handy is if the image had to be run with arbitrary privileges:

```
docker container run --privileged ...
```

Can you escalate from `--privileged` to root? I don't know you can not.  I would rather assume you can and isolate the docker.

Since OP has one simple static predetermined docker command that OP is confident can not be escalated, I feel https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876910/348975 is the preferred solution.

If you are paranoid, you can use both https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876910/348975 and my solution together.

Answer (score -1):

Create the docker group and add your user to the docker group.

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

You can follow docker documentation for more details [manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: Users in group docker are privileged and can do arbitrary changes to the host system. Being member of group docker is root-equivalent.